# How to develop a C#.NET application for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2008, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I want to create a desktop application using C#.net (Database - SQL Server ) which is run on Ubuntu 12.04 operating system.

How can I convert my C# .Net code into something compatible with Ubuntu?

Comment: Check out Mono, an implementation of the C# compiler and .NET framework for Linux: http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) to develop C# applications which can run on Linux

In terms of using SQL Server with Linux you can use the [SQL Server® ODBC Driver 1.0 for Linux](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=28160)

Comment: Thank you. i have a another question. if i use mono can i develop this application in windows platform and use it in Ubuntu or will i develop on Ubuntu platform ?

Comment: you can download mono for [Windows and Ubuntu platforms](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html) so you can write your programs for either and deploy on either

Answer (score 2):

Use the open-source [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) framework